# Gracefuly stop .net initiated Java Process

Tags: c#, java, .net, windows-services, process

Having the next .net code, I want to stop it correctly so that the jvm executes it's ShutdownHooks.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\test\";
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6u16\bin\java.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar TheExecutable.jar";
```

Trying to stop the process with p.Kill() will force the jvm to stop without sending the equivalent SIGTERM found in the unix kill comand. Or maeby I am doing something wrong because the java process does not get it's shutdown hooks executed.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the Java code, you could detect a fairly normal situation like End-Of-File in `stdin`, or a so-called poison pill in `stdin`, and use that to decide (in Java) that now is the time to exit.

Then to kill the java process, do whatever is needed to its `stdin`.

Another option is to write a signal handler, - `see sun.misc.SignalHandler`, and register this with `sum.misc.Signal`

Other options seem rather hideous - like polling the parent process or looking at a file.

Comment: By the way, would you explain please why in windows in this specific case we can't do what in linux whould have work sending a SIGTERM ?